# Expected balancing behavior when restoring data with mongorestore to a sharded cluster

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I have noticed that when restoring data with mongorestore to a sharded cluster through mongos, all the records are initially saved to the primary shard (of the collection) and only the balancer process moves these chunks, which is a relatively slow process, so right after restore I have a similar situation:

```
chunks:
    rs_shard-1  28
    rs_shard-2  29
    rs_shard-4  27
    rs_shard-3  644
```

I don't have any errors in the mongodb/mongos log files.

I'm not sure, but I think that in the past data was restored in an already balanced way. Now I'm using version 2.4.6. Can someone confirm what is the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what happens imho:

When restoring the data, there are initial ranges for chunks assigned to each shard. The data is inserted by `mongorestore` without waiting for any responses from `mongos`, not speaking of the shards, resulting in a relatively fast insertion of the documents. I assume that you have a monotonically increasing shard key, like ObjectId for example. Now what happens is that one shard has been assigned the range from X to infinite (called "maxKey" in mongoland) during the initial assignment of chunk ranges. The documents in this range will be created on that shard, resulting in a lot of chunk splits and an increasing number of chunks on that server. A chunk split will trigger a balancer round, but since the insertion of new documents is faster than the chunk migration, the number of chunks will increase faster than the balancer can reduce it.

So what I would do is to check the shard key. I am pretty sure that it is monotonically increasing. Which is bad not only when restoring a backup, but in production use, too. Please see [shard key documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/#shard-keys) and [Considerations for Selecting Shard Keys](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/choose-a-shard-key/) in the MongoDB docs.

A few additional notes. The `mongodump` utility is designed for small databases, like the config db of a sharded cluster. Your database has a size of roughly 46.5GB which isn't exactly small. I'd rather use file system snapshots on each individual shard, synchronized using a cronjob. If you *really* need a point in time recovery, you can still use `mongodump` in direct file access mode on the snapshotted files to create a dump and restore those dumps using the `--oplogLimit` option. Other than the ability to do a point in time recovery, the usage of `mongodump` has no advantage over taking file system snapshots, but has the disadvantage that you have to stop the balancer in order to have a consistent backup and to lock the database during the whole backup procedure in order to have a true point in time recovery option.